# rename multiple filename in linux

Tags: linux, filenames, rename

I have many files named **xxxx.min.js** and want to rename the files to **xxxx.js** so basically want to remove **.min** only.

Is there a command I can use to do this job?

I thought using rename command would be easy for each single file, but that would take forever since I have many of them.

any idea?

Comment: Then you're using the `rename` command wrong.

Comment: But why aren't you handling it in your web server in the first place?

Comment: I want to do that on my web server, but maybe I'm using it wrong... not sure how!!

Comment: Erm, you do it in your rewrite rules...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the right idea to rename .min.js files to .js as they're meant to be named like that.

Comment: but if I want them like that, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bash-only command (not requiring Perl)

```
 for i in *.min.js; do a=$(basename $i .min.js); echo mv $i $a.js; done
```

Explanation

```
 for i in *.min.js; do
```

loop over all files matching `*.min.js`

```
 a=$(basename $i .min.js)
```

extract the base name of the file (i.e. strip off `.min.js`) and save the result in `$a`

```
echo mv $i $a.js
```

for now, print to the console the command that WOULD be run if you removed the `echo`

When you are satisfied that it generates the correct commands, remove the `echo` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu and Debian linux distribution both have a perl version of `mv` function called `rename` or `prename`, which supports regexp. The manual can be found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html).

Go to the folder of the files and run the command as follows:

```
rename s/\.min\.js$/\.js/ *.min.js
```

Comment: I think there is something incorrect in this command...!! is it `’`??

Comment: I have changed the mistake and tested on my Ubuntu VM. It should work fine now. It's really wired because the `’` is copied from Ubuntu manual.

Comment: The `rename` command is also on Fedora (and presumably RedHat/CentOS), for future reference.

Comment: is it the same for Debian/Ubuntu Linux? possibly it is `mv`